# How to: Display MKOverlay on MKMapView

Tags: ios, ios5, mapkit, mkoverlay

I need to display an MKOverlay on a map, but can't get it to actually appear.

I'm following the [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html) from Apple's [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html) and the overlay wont display.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is the first iPhone app I've made, so I might be missing something simple.

NavViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface NavViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

NavViewController.m

```
#import "MSUNavViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonView* aView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay];

        aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        aView.lineWidth = 3;

        return aView;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Define an overlay that covers Colorado.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  points[4];

    points[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.000512, -109.050116);
    points[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.002371, -102.052066);
    points[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.993076, -102.041981);
    points[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.99892, -109.045267);

    MKPolygon* poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:4];
    poly.title = @"Colorado";

    [_mapView addOverlay:poly];
}
```

Storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

Any coding suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to set mapView's `delegate` to the view controller instance( perhaps `File's owner` in this case).

In interface builder, right-click on the map view, drag from hollowed circle at the right of delegate, to the File's Owner icon at the Placeholder section in the pane on the left.

For storyboard, connect to the View Controller icon instead of File's Owner.

Comment: How exactly do I set the delegate to the view controller instance?
I'm new to this.

Comment: Right click on the nib's map view, first check if the MKMapView's referencing outlet is mapView - File's Owner, then check if its `delegate` outlet is `File's owner`.

Comment: it looks like the delegate isn't set and I can't figure out how to set it to `File's owner'.  Also, I'm on IOS 5, so the File's owner icon doesn't appear.

Comment: Look at the picture. Drag from delegate circle to the yellow big circle at the bottom of the screen.

Or add `_mapView.delegate = self;` to - (void)viewDidLoad method

Comment: drag from hollowed circle at the right of `delegate`, to the `File's Owner` icon at the `Placeholder` section in the pane on the left.

Comment: On IOS 5, the `File's Owner` icon isn't present.
To do the same thing, I added the line of code
`_mapView.delegate = self;` above `[_mapView addOverlay:poly];`

Comment: Maybe you are using storyboard. So, drag to the view controller (besides firstResponder) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you killing aView in `- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay` by `return nil;`
Try to add `else` before.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonView* aView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay];

        aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        aView.lineWidth = 3;

        return aView;
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve your problem? Just drag from the circle beside delegate (in your screen shot) to the circle which is the name of the class..  there is a setting in the inspector that would allow you to display where you are also..? You made need to centre the map in say viewDidLoad so it displays over Colorado..