# Add button to MKPointAnnotation

Tags: swift, mkpointannotation

Having a problem when i try to add a button in a annotation.

Before i've asked this question i've searched for answers on the following pages:
[How to add a button to the MKPointAnnotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225296/how-can-i-add-a-button-to-mkpointannotation)
, [Adding a button to MKPointAnnotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610286/adding-a-button-to-mkpointannotation)
etc.
But all couldn't help me.

This what is tried to do:

```
var annotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation1.setCoordinate(locationKamer1)
annotation1.title = "Title1"
annotation1.subtitle = "Subtitle1"
// here i want to add a button which has a segue to another page.
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation1)
```

Don't know if what i try to do isn't working. 
I'm experimenting with swift for the first time.

Hope someone can help me :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a button to MKPointAnnotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225296/how-can-i-add-a-button-to-mkpointannotation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That answer in your first link is basically right, though it needs to be updated for Swift 2.

Bottom line, in answer to your question, you don't add the button when you create the annotation. You create the button when you create its annotation view in `viewForAnnotation`.

So, you should:

1. Set the view controller to be the delegate of the map view.
2. Make the view controller conform to the map view delegate protocol, e.g.:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate { ... }
   ```
3. Add a segue from the view controller (not the button) to the next scene by <kbd>control</kbd> dragging from the view controller icon above the scene with the map view to the next scene:

   [image]

   Then select that segue and then give it a storyboard identifier ("NextScene" in my example, though you should use a more descriptive name):

   [image]
4. Implement `viewForAnnotation` to add button as right accessory.

   ```
   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
       var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(annotationIdentifier)
       if view == nil {
           view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
           view?.canShowCallout = true
           view?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
       } else {
           view?.annotation = annotation 
       }
       return view
   }
   ```
5. Implement `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` which (a) captures which annotation was tapped; and (b) initiates the segue:

   ```
   var selectedAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation!

   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
       if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
           selectedAnnotation = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation
           performSegueWithIdentifier("NextScene", sender: self)
       }
   }
   ```
6. Implement a `prepareForSegue` that will pass the necessary information (presumably you want to pass the annotation and therefore have a `annotation` property in that second view controller).

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
           destination.annotation = selectedAnnotation
       }
   }
   ```
7. Now you can create your annotation like you were before:

   ```
   let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
   annotation.coordinate = coordinate
   annotation.title = "Title1"
   annotation.subtitle = "Subtitle1"
   mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob, i didn't understand the principle that i don't add the button when i create the annotation. Now its more clear for me!